# Show earned badges summary in the user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, usability, navigation

What do you think about adding the earned badges summary in the user profile?

[image]

### Why?

I'm aware that *badges summary* is pretty pervasive in several sections of the sites like *Users tab*, *Questions* and *Answers*.

I think that this information could be useful if someone is visiting the user profile from a comment, where badges are not reported.

Check this navigation pattern:

1. reading a questions/answers
2. find an hilarious comment
3. click on the user link
4. check who that guy/girl is<sup>*</sup> and his/her profile with badges
5. can't find that information
6. search user with Users tab

Personally I've stumbled into this pattern several times and from an usability standpoint, I'd like to see the badges summary in the user profile.

The same pattern can be applied to the **Top Questions** section where badges are not displayed.
[image]

What do you think?

<sup>*Ok I know, Jon Skeet is not a great example here</sup>

**UPDATE:**
this is now completed!

Comment: +1 for using Jon Skeet as an example here.

Comment: Who is Jon Skeet?

Comment: This would be nice, especially since the news users page will show users with rep weekly/monthly etc without the badge summary unless you hit `all`.

Comment: @ Closure Cowboy- see answer no. 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will address this in a future user page redesign.

Comment: and I guess the planned way of addressing it is different enough to justify [status-declined] instead of [status-deferred] ?

Comment: @Daniel updated

Answer (score 13):

That would be a great summation line for the badges shown at the bottom of the user profile page.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is time to revisit this question again.  I have just answered this question [Should the sportsmanship badge be awarded multiple times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81450/156011) and to provide more info, I was interested to know how many silver badges HRH Jon Skeet had.

Well, I duly went to /users, where HRH has permanent residence.  The new user card shows more details, but no badge summary (I cannot recall if it had, before the change).

That's cool - let's click through to the user profile - no dice.

This is getting tricky, I choose one of HRH's answers - still no dice (I happened to pick one of the first questions showing, which was a CW).

At this point, it just feels stupid and frustrating - **how hard should it be to see someone's badge summary**?  With the user profile being expanded vertically far below the 2nd column, surely the badge summary can sit snugly there?

---

**Q: Hey officer, you have 4 stripes - is that a high rank?**

A: I don't know, we rank by salary, not stripes

The analogy is that while badges decorate and in some cases mean more, salary is what brings home the bacon.

Which is better?

```
Rep 10k, Badges 1 G,  2 S, 17 B
vs
Rep  5k, Badges 4 G, 10 S,  6 B
```

I don't know, but I would like to see both carry equal prominence in all places.

Comment: I also don't see why not. If the site's code is reasonably well written, it shouldn't be much more work than a single method call, and it's got to be a reasonably efficient method to call, since it appears on every page header, so it shouldn't add too much system overhead. Granted, it's never going to be the highest priority thing to change, but for the amount of work involved, surely it could be slipped in?

Comment: @systempuntoout Thanks :) I just got past 2000 and I love being able to do more with the privileges. But give it another couple of weeks, I'll slap another 500 on this question.

Comment: thanks for the multimillionaire Bounty :)

Answer (score 3):

The badges are listed in detail on the bottom of the user profile page, so in my mind a summary at the top is not needed.

Your example of navigation based on comments is valid, but I would assume the majority of the time people click on a user profile, they do so from a question, answer, or user page.  All of which contain this summary already.

Comment: You expect to count Jon Skeet's badges instead of seeing a ready summary?

Comment: @cyber, Jon Skeet's badges are already totaled on every one of his posts, edits, and on the user page.  So you see the total before you click on his profile for the detail.

Comment: The million dollar question is - since it's so pervasive, "why not?" Do you have something against it?

Comment: @cyber, I guess the reason why not is that it is necessary.  There are plenty of other features that do increase usability that I would like to see completed instead of working on this request.

Comment: Since this **is** meta where we discuss and propose stuff, is there an alternative site/queue for lower priority feature requests? Btw, you're also saying, why have the reputation in gigantic font on the user page. reduce its size by just 1 and put the badge summary under it.

Comment: @Cyber, I like the size on the font.  And since the badge summary is next to a large majority of the links to the user profile, I think it is not needed on the user page.   So I propose we don't make this change at all.