# Should the sportsmanship badge be awarded multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, badges

At present it looks like the sportsmanship badge is only awarded once (at least I assume this because it doesn't explicitly say it's awarded multiple times on the badge page.) Would it make sense to change this so it's awarded multiple times, so it works for every 100 competing answers upvoted?

I doubt this feature would be abused since it involves essentially putting your answers at a disadvantage, and it'd still encourage people to keep on fairly upvoting competing answers even after they've already upvoted 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I doubt this feature would be abused since it involves essentially putting your answers at a disadvantage

Well yes, only if you had an answer in the first place. I could just as well put junk answers onto 30 questions and vote up the proper answers, you know. Every 10 days, bam - 3 silver medals. The possibilities are mind boggling!  <s>I can get more silvers than Jon Skeet! (unless his highness does the same...)</s>

#### EDIT

It was a mission* but I found the info I was looking for. I guess this [Jon Skeet fact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9135/156011/) is true

- Jon Skeet has more "Nice Answer" badges than you have badges.

Jon can generate [good-answer](/questions/tagged/good-answer) badges faster than you can farm the [sportsmanship](/questions/tagged/sportsmanship) badge change you propose. That's something.

(*Please can people upvote this: [Show earned badges summary in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73110/156011)?)

Comment: Posting junk answers would result in a lot of downvoting.  I think people care too much about rep (even more than about badges!) to let that happen to themselves.

Comment: @john - you came in the wrong way. What's more true is that if you posted a so-so answer (even one that is copied), people are more likely to **ignore** your answer **without** downvoting for exactly that reason - to protect their precious rep. You may even get one or to upvotes.

Comment: True, but that's a *so-so* answer.  You *were* talking about *junk* answers.  To me, there is a difference.  :-)

Comment: @richard true! people won't usually downvote unless they really think its bad, but upvotes are free and people do that more often.

Comment: You know that your answer has to have at least one upvote for it to qualify, right?  It'd be pretty hard to game without actually posting useful content and then you're not really gaming it as much as you are being forced to post useful content.

Comment: @Daniel / Good point, I never read the fine print. I just rarely put answers that get no votes :) so I don't notice.  But it's still easy to copy/paste (mod a bit) in the early life of a question and get a couple of votes.