# Adding Edits to user profile page

Tags: feature-request, edits, profile-page

Currently the user profile show Questions asked by the user and Answers posted by him/her.

Since users can now suggest edits as well, I think it would be good idea to add **"Edits"** section as well, showing what posts the user has edited or suggested to edit.

Not sure if to apply this to all users or just <2K rep users that can only suggest an edit - want your opinions on this matter. :-)

Just noticed that such information is available in the *Activity* tab but still, would be nicer to have it in the main tab as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, this already exists:

- [Your edits (called "revisions")](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions)
- [The edits you've approved/rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews)

The main user page is about *you*: your biography, reputation, and content. Your revisions and reviews are your *activity*, which is why they're on the activity page.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of those shortcuts.. still would be nice to make it more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Please, please **don't**.

I would even ask for the profile page to be reduced in detail, splitting into tabs if required.
Anything you add (section, not single-liners like [badge summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73110/show-earned-badges-summary-in-the-user-profile)) to the page will just make it even longer and slower to load.

There are other things missing, like revisions, edits, approvals, comments... show them all? - **no!**

Comment: Personally I prefer to have all the information in one page, with links to more details and paging where required. Since edits became important part when low rep members can do it, I think it need to be shown in the same place as Questions and Answers. Regarding slower to load it's easy to load everything with AJAX after initial page load so that's not a real problem.

Comment: @Shadow - but are you **always** interested in all the details about yourself **all the time**, each visit to your profile page (AJAX doesn't solve bandwidth burn)? Given it's also the landing page for others visiting your profile, do you think it also applies to others (even less so)

Comment: Yes the "trigger" for my request was after I saw question edited by low rep member and I wanted to see what other posts that member has edited, so I'd like to see all those details in other profiles as well. Regarding bandwidth I really don't think those extra <1K bytes will bring SE down. :-)