# Should the Answers section be displayed before the Questions on user profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

I noticed an ongoing discussion on what's more valuable for the community: Questions or Answers?

Clearly the reputation system values answers more. Also the current discussion about ["cap reputation gained from questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/should-we-cap-reputation-gained-from-questions-at-2000) goes in that direction.

Shouldn't the user profile reflect this by changing the order of the sections so that answers are displayed before the questions?

1. **User Info**
2. **Answers**
3. **Questions**
4. **Votes**
5. **Tags**
6. **Badges**

I would also believe, that **0 Answers** as first headline after the user info (and that's on most screens what you see without scrolling) would be encouraging at least some users to answer a couple of questions just to get rid of this big fat zero answers below their reputation.

Comment: Here's a link to my deleted answer where Nick Craver commented that the proposed tab order would be implemented (10k only): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112238

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the recent changes to the user profile page this feature is now implemented:

- **If a user has more answers than questions the answers section will appear before the questions section in the summary tab**
- The tab order itself is always "summary, answers, questions" and will not be effected

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would be more happy with this, but other than that, great idea!

1. User Info *
2. Answers
3. Questions
4. Tags
5. Votes
6. Badges

Better if they start collapsed and get retrieved via AJAX only when opened (bandwidth conscious)

* *would be great if we could include a [badge summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73110/156011) at point 1*

Answer (score 2):

I would rather have "intelligent" algorithm, for example if user has more Answers than Questions then show this section first.

This will give the more relevant information first - for someone who asked only 5 questions but answered 1000 the answers are more relevant but someone who asked 1000 and answered only 5? Probably the answers are less relevant.

Regarding 0 Answers, maybe it's worth adding some color somewhere same way the Accept Rate is being colored.

Comment: +1 What is SO if its not a big worked example of machine learning

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem. On my profile it would show answers first because I already answer far more questions than I ask. The point is to encourage those who ask more than they answer to "give something back". Showing that they have 0 (or < 10) answers before showing their 100+ questions might do this.

Comment: No, having this inconsistent behaviour doesn't sound like a good idea. I want to know _in advance_ where I'm going to find certain information on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the members page could become more of a igoogle-like SE portal, where users can position (or hide) a series of page building blocks (throw in reputation graph, cross-se-stats, comments etc).  Let people choose what they want to see.

I think that a portal approach will be more and more relevant as more questions are moved about in the SE community and more people start to open programmers, webmasters etc accounts as a result.

Comment: Oh no, please not. What I like very much on stackexchange is _consistent layout_.