# Questions and Answers section switched on the user profile

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the Answers section be displayed before the Questions on user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83117/should-the-answers-section-be-displayed-before-the-questions-on-user-profiles)

I noticed that in some user profiles the place of the Questions and the Answers section are switched, so the Questions section is in the top left.

So for most users the Questions section is in the top left, but for some the Answers section is there. I've found no pattern that could explain which users are affected by this.

And in one even more curious case where I only see the Questions section in the top left when I view the profile while logged in (as moderator in this case), but the Answers section is in the top left for anonymous users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these users have one thing in common: They have **more questions than answers**. My guess is, whatever you have more of, questions or answers, is displayed first in your profile.

As for that mystery user: Since you, as a moderator, can dig up dirt on your subjects, you see deleted content in user profiles, right? So you would get more questions/answers when logged in, which could re-order the sections, depending on how many deleted posts there are.

Comment: That's correct. The orders are reshuffled depending on how many posts in each category the user has. [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114041/), and [other reference (10k+ only)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live/112238#112238)