# Sometimes "Answers" is higher than "Questions" on the user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

[image]

It seems like sometimes, users' answers are placed higher than their questions on the user profile. While it certainly makes sense to put questions higher if the user has no answers, it feels inconsistent.

Can it be changed so that answers are always higher than questions?

Comment: Why questions ahead of answers, and not the reverse?

Comment: @HDE226868 I thought about it for a bit, and have decided to reverse it (still not sure though, it can really go both ways). My main point is that it should be consistent across sites.

Comment: @animuson isn't this more of a "status-bydesign"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per "[Should the Answers section be displayed before the Questions on user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114041/254554)" post:

> With the recent changes to the user profile page this feature is now
>   implemented:
>
> If a user has more answers than questions the answers section will
>   appear before the questions section in the summary tab

Please see the screenshot given in the linked answer showing an example of summary tab where user has more *questions* than *answers* in that case the questions section appear before the answers section.

As per moderator animuson's comment:

> To expand, this is very intentional because we want to display the
>   most relevant information first. If a user always answers questions
>   and rarely asks them, then it makes more sense to show answers first
>   because that's what they do more often. On the converse, for a user
>   that only ever asks questions and rarely answers, you would want to
>   see their questions listed first.

The above answers your 'Exhibit A' and 'Exhibit B' Q&A display order.

As for 'Exhibit C' and 'Exhibit D' goes, where animuson says: (copied from comment)

> The current behavior only becomes "inconsistent" in a sense when a
>   user equally contributes both questions and answers to the site.

I would like to also add one of my finding i.e. 'Answers' section always takes a priority i.e. appears before the questions section whenever a user equally contributes both questions and answers. Apart from [Op's Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/210972/jeffrey-lin?tab=topactivity) profile(3,3) I also checked few other user's profile e.g. [Lance Roberts](https://serverfault.com/users/5947/lance-roberts?tab=topactivity) (12,12), [Anna Lear ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/1412/anna-lear?tab=topactivity) (2,2), [animuson ♦](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13/animuson?tab=topactivity) (3,3) and it appears to be like that. Here is what animuson says (copied from comment):

> Appears so. Intentional? I've no idea. Likely a developer used a
>   greater than somewhere, didn't pay attention to which one would end up
>   on top if they were the same, and no one's really cared which one it
>   should actually be. I'm going to say it's fine since it matches the
>   order of the tabs above?

Comment: To expand, this is very intentional because we want to display the most relevant information first. If a user always answers questions and rarely asks them, then it makes more sense to show answers first because that's what they do more often. On the converse, for a user that only ever asks questions and rarely answers, you would want to see their questions listed first. The current behavior only becomes "inconsistent" in a sense when a user equally contributes both questions and answers to the site.

Comment: @animuson I agree I think it makes sense to show the most relevant information closest to the top. Do you mind if I include ur comment in my post?

Comment: Sure, go for it. :)

Comment: @animuson Thanks. Another thing I found in case of OP's shared 'Exhibit C' and 'Exhibit D' is that 'Answers' section always takes priority when they are same count, is that correct?

Comment: Appears so. Intentional? I've no idea. Likely a developer used a greater than somewhere, didn't pay attention to which one would end up on top if they were the same, and no one's really cared which one it should actually be. I'm going to say it's fine since it matches the order of the tabs above?